# How to Obtain SQL Statement generated by FME?

Tags: sql-server, fme

I have an FME workbench that has started performing poorly.  My hunch is that it's DB related.  How can I determine exactly the SQL that FME is sending to the DB?  I can get with the DBA's and perform a trace; however it may not give me the complete picture. I would prefer to obtain this information from FME if possible.

SQL Server Version: 2012 
FME Version: 2017.0.0.2

Comment: SQL Profiler will show you every single statement being executed against your server.

Comment: If it's in a cursor, then won't it not give me a complete picture?  Just the same code over and over again.

Comment: One would hope the parameters change. Otherwise what would be the point of the cursor? You can see the full statement including parameters and where conditions in a trace.

Answer (score 1):

The FME logs themselves should show you give you the full SQL statement, however that behaviour may change depending on whether there is an error or not on run time.

You don't specify if its a SQL reader you are using or a SQL executor? I would turn the debugging mode on for the logs which is much more verbose and should give you full details on DB connections etc.

[FME dubugging options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wP7E0.jpg)